# How to prevent this code from echoing using ob_get_contents();

Tags: php, session

This is what i have:

```
    ob_start();
    for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['checkbox_checker']);$i++) {
    echo "<br />".$_POST['checkbox_checker'][$i];
    $selection = ob_end_flush();
    }
```

I am then using $selection to store in a database since i am unable to find a way to use sessions to store checkboxes.  The problem is when i use $SELECTION = ob_end_flush(); the values still echo.  How can i make it so the values that are supposed to be echoed get stored inside of $selection and don't show to the user?

Comment: That's what [`ob_end_flush()`](http://php.net/ob_end_flush) does. It flushes the collected output. It doesn't even return the buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual solution, btw, would be to not use the `echo`. You don't need that workaround if you just append to a string variable:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['checkbox_checker']);$i++) {
   $str .=  "<br />".$_POST['checkbox_checker'][$i];
}
```

(And you could also read up on [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach). Or even [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode) in this case.)

Comment: Yet another case where OB diables people to see the actual solution(s)!

Answer (score 2):

Use `ob_get_clean();`

```
ob_start();
for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['checkbox_checker']);$i++) {
   echo "<br />".$_POST['checkbox_checker'][$i];
}
$selection = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: `ob_get_clean` does not turn off output buffering.

Comment: @Arjan It has and does for me. it returns a string.

Comment: @Arjan see here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php "Gets the current buffer contents and **delete current output buffer**."

Comment: In that case I blame the PHP manpages. For `ob_get_flush` it explicitly states **and turns off output buffering**. That's not specified for `ob_get_clean`. It is however specified for `ob_end_clean`, so maybe I should have read that too.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ob_get_flush()`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-flush.php) instead. ;)

Comment: Haha aint that the @Truth :-D `+1`

Answer (score 1):

ob_end_clean() - Clean (erase) the output buffer and turn off output buffering

where as

ob_end_flush - Flush (send) the output buffer and turn off output buffering

Answer (score 0):

[`ob_end_flush`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php) returns a boolean, whereas [`ob_get_flush`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-flush.php) returns a string. The latter is the function you need.